# SortedAscending/Descending Styles not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I'm having trouble with the Sorted Styles in my gridview, they are simply not being applied, be it cellstyle, headerstyle, color etc...

Maybe it's because of the way i'm sorting my dataview? It's like the framework isn't seeing the column as being sorted...

```
protected void dgvOpps_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortDirection = "ASC";
    string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;

    if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
        sortDirection = "DESC";

    ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
    ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;

    string orderByCol = e.SortExpression;

    DataTable dt;

    if (Session["dgvOppsFilter"] != null)
        dt = ldcrmClient.RetrieveOpportunitiesOfReseller(loggedUser.account_id, (string[])Session["dgvOppsFilter"], new string[0]);
    else dt = ldcrmClient.RetrieveOpportunitiesOfReseller(loggedUser.account_id, new string[0], new string[0]);

    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortDirection;

    Session.Add("dgvOppsSort", e.SortExpression + " " + sortDirection);

    dgvOpps.DataSource = dv;
    dgvOpps.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
                    ViewState["sortDirection"] = "asc";

                if (ViewState["sortExpression"] == null)
                    ViewState["sortExpression"] = "your-column-name";
               // Fill the Grid
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Sorting:

```
protected void dgvOpps_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortDirection"]) == "asc")
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = "desc";
        else
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = "asc";


        ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
// Feetch dt here according to your code
          if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dt.DefaultView.Sort = Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortExpression"]) + " " + Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortDirection"]);
                dgvOpps.DataSource =dt;
                dgvOpps.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                dgvOpps.DataSource = null;
                dgvOpps.DataBind();

            }
    }
```

Comment: tried exactly what you posted and still no style applied to the TH or TD at all when i sort the columns.